# How to add app logo on video in android

Tags: java, android, video, bitmap, ffmpeg

I have a video stored in my internal storage. I want to add the app logo to the video and play it in my android app.

I have googled a bit and got the following results,

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

[Adding watermark bitmap over video in android: 4.3's MediaMuxer or ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489/adding-watermark-bitmap-over-video-in-android-4-3s-mediamuxer-or-ffmpeg)

But from these references i am not getting how to implement the feature which i want.
So can any one please help me out in finding the solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

There is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37957424/8289261

> FFmpeg4Android is a way your application can run FFmpeg commands, 
>   only Java, no need for C code, or NDK.

Direct link, look for 'watermark' command
http://androidwarzone.blogspot.ru/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Commands example from that page ():

```
 WaterMark:
 //  test with watermark.png 128x128, add it to /sdcard/videokit/
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", "/sdcard/videokit/in.mp4","-strict","experimental", "-vf", "movie=/sdcard/videokit/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]","-s", "320x240","-r", "30", "-b", "15496k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4","-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "/sdcard/videokit/out.mp4"};
```